# best alternative algo for sort/manipulate/sort

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I need a better algo for following situation:
   Log file containing data from two sensors i.e. number of entries are available for given time and are appended one below other e.g.

```
time < no. entries 1> < no. entries 2>

2

3

3

time < no. entries 1> < no. entries 2>

..

..
```

Currently i can read the file and after dynamically allocating the memory i built an list, which is sorted. Certain manipulation at the top 3 entries which may result in decrease the values currently it posses. After this i need to sort again and manipulate until one of the array is completely empty.

Please suggest a better algorithm for this situation since the continuous sorting is taking long time after every manipulation. 
   Can i use b-trees or any other method to reduce the time? Also the file can go beyond 100MB so please suggest optimization for reading and building a list of array.

Comment: What is the nature of the manipulation which you are doing? Is the manipulation only done for the top 3 elements, or can that number be more?

Comment: You need to provide far more info.

Comment: manipulation for now we can consider as substraction i.e. the higher value (either in array1 or array2) will be reduced to the lower and we can discard the lower value from the array for next round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to implement a custom priority queue for your needs. You can implement a `binary-heap` which would act as your priority queue. Read more about on [this Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap).

The cost of forming the heap is O(n) from a list of `n` elements.

In general, binary-heaps only expose the methods `push()`, `pop()`, `front()` or `peek()` to the programmer which have O(log n) complexity for insertion and deletion. They have the methods `heap-up()` or `heap-down()` as private, which are called internally by `push()` and `pop()` respectively, and thus they cause the `heap` property to be maintained.

I'm asking you to implement a custom priority queue as you need to manipulate the entries of the queue, **which *may*** cause the order of elements to change. You can use an `std::vector` as your container for the Priority Queue. You would need the following extra stuff:

- Provide an overloaded `operator []` which returns a `const` reference to the indexed element.
- If you decide to alter the `key` or the `rank` of an element which would alter the order of elements, you can do so by providing a `replace(int iIndex, const Type &item)` method which replaces the element at `iIndex` with the element `item` but preserves the ordering of elements.

Here is what it may look like:

```
template <class Type>
bool PriorityQueue<Type>::Replace(int iIndex, const Type &item ){
    if ( iIndex < m_itemList.size() ) {        
        if ( item < m_itemList[ iIndex ] ) {
            m_itemList[ iIndex ] = item;
            HeapUp( iIndex );
        }
        else {
            m_itemList[ iIndex ] = item;
            HeapDown( iIndex );
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So the `replace()` method automatically calls the `heapUp()` or the `heapDown()` internally to preserve the heap property. The complexity of this would again be O(log n) at worse.

The `operator []` should return a const reference to the program so that you don't abuse it accidentally and corrupt your heap ordering. The only change in the heap should be done by the `replace()` method.

Comment: Thanks for wonderful suggestion. I will require always a sorted PQ hence existing ordering doesn't matter. Is there any method to delay the sorting since as soon as i manipulate and reinsert the new value the queue gets sorted. e.g. previous values where 30 20 10 and once i manipulate the top() i.e. 30 to 25 and reinsert i get 25 where as i need 20.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want `20` instead of `25` even though its smaller. Can't think of a direct method for doing that, as then it would require to figure out _when exactly_ should the ordering be triggered. One thing which you can do then, is to `pop()` out the top 3 elements, do the manipulation, and `push()` them back in the queue. But in this case then, you wouldn't require the `replace()` method at all. Please bear in mind that the elements are not being sorted here but only ordered as per a `heap`.

Comment: thanks again, actually the pop() push() method i tried out now and for an 100MB file it has took (real) 1m30s previous was (real) 5m which is much better than my current implementation. So far i have not implemented replace() method.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell exactly what you're doing, but it *sounds* like you want a data structure where is is efficient to:

- Find & remove the top N entries sorted by some key;
- Insert an entry.

The name for this is a Priority Queue.  There are many ways to implement an efficient priority queue.

Comment: thanks caf, the priority queue has worked for me as you can check the statistics above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `std::set`, `std::map`, and their `multi` cousins? These containers always stay sorted no matter what order you insert or remove elements, and they are easy to use.

Comment: i thing these ds would be costly as i need only integers to be worked with. I will give it a try and profile them soon. Thanks for answer.